# Creating a nested Javascript Object from an array of Strings

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to create a N levels nested object (where N is the size of the array) for example:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c','d']
```

The output object should look like this:

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also include the code that you wrote that isn't properly working.

Comment: Use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) with `true` as initialValue `arr.reduceRight((r, k) =>  ({ [k]: r }), true)  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), it helps you pass an accumulator where you can accumulate your nested obj.

```js
const array = ['a','b','c','d'];
const object = {};
array.reduce((o, s) => { 
  return o[s] = {};
}, object);
console.log(object);
```